# Adding functional tests to a Backbone.js application

Tags: backbone.js, tdd, functional-testing

I'm sorry if this question isn't appropriate: I'm new to test-driven development, especially on JavaScript.

I have a working Backbone.js application, and I'd like to add some JavaScript tests to it. But I don't really know where to start.

Specifically, I'd like to write tests that are passed a URL, and check that the rendered page contains particular DOM elements. (So functional tests, rather than unit tests, I guess.)

What is a good way to do this? Could anyone recommend good practical resources for getting tests like this up and running?

Apologies for the newbie question.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem lately and Ryan Roemer book Backbone.js Testing (http://backbone-testing.com/) is a great place to start.

His process is not purely TDD, but he gives some nice tips.

When taking it to practice, I will recommend a Yeoman generator like:

- https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette (Marionette)
- https://github.com/revathskumar/generator-backbone-mocha (Backbone and Mocha)
- https://github.com/richistron/generator-cornelio (Karma and Backbone)

They will save you some time on the setup. Also, if you are using Rails, Konacha https://github.com/jfirebaugh/konacha has been pretty handy for me.

Good testing!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is on de-factor way to run functional tests in the browser. Selenium has a firefox plugin that will record actions and replay them. That would be the easiest way to start. You can look at Selenium's API docs to write code to interact with the browser.

Sause Labs (http://saucelabs.com/docs/quickstart) has selenium in the cloud which is useful so you don't need to have a browser window open on you desktop and run the tests. PhantomJS can also run a "headless" browser (it does't open a window on you computer, just runs in the background).

Once you have selenium working you might want to look into acceptance testing. The tests are written in plain english use Gherkin (or similar) syntax and it runs functions to run the test and output reports if there were errors or not.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an article how to use Selenium for Acceptance Testing http://alex-craft.com/blog/2014/acceptance-testing-for-web-app

Tools: WebDriver (Selenium or Phantom.js), wd.js, node.js, mocha.js.

There's an example with explanation how to use meaningful names instead of CSS selectors, eventual conditions, etc.